# "napa" office 365 app not available in sharepoint store

Tags: sharepoint, office365-apps, napa

I have been trying to add the "Napa" office 365 development tools app for my Office 365 developer site. But I'm not able to find the app in the sharepoint store. When searched directly in the office store, it is said: "This item has been removed from the store" (Please refer to the image attached). 
Could anyone please help me in finding the Napa app?

Thanks in Advance,
Keerthi

[Napa app from office store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0Aay.png)

Answer (score 0):

This add-in isn’t available right now. Check back later to see if an updated version is available.

IMPORTANT: New name for apps for Office - Office Add-ins. We are currently updating our products, documentation, samples, and other resources to reflect the platform name change from "apps for Office and SharePoint" to "Office and SharePoint Add-ins". We made this change to better distinguish the extension platform from Office apps (applications). While these changes are taking place, the dialogs and messages you see in your application might be different than what you see in this article.